# Double pointers with Objective-C. Change where a pointer points to.

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

I have a UITableView where I have two data sources.

```
@property(strong)NSArray* mediaItems;
@property(strong)NSArray* likesItems;
```

In a lot of cases I need to swap both of the sources out. As a result there is a lot of if statements where I check

```
if (self.activePage == kDrawingsPage) self.mediaItems = responseObject;
else self.likesItems = responseObject;
```

What I would like to do is not need to keep checking like this. Using a double pointer. Could I not use a double pointer to do something like. (this does not work)

```
NSArray** activeItems = &self.mediaItems;
```

Then in places where I need to access the data I can simply do

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 NSArray* arr = *self.activeItems;
 return [arr count];
 }
```

Instead of

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (self.activePage == kDrawingsPage) [self.mediaItems count];
else [self.likesItems count];
 }
```

Shouldn't a double pointer or something similar work in this case? If it cannot work what other way can I minimize these if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use computed property

in `@interface`

```
@property (readonly) NSArray* activeItems;
```

in `@implementation`

```
- (NSArray *)activeItems {
    return self.activePage == kDrawingsPage ? self.mediaItems : self.likesItems
}
```

so you can do

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [self.activeItems count];
}
```

---

`&self.mediaItems` won't give you any meaningful value, because it is same as `&[self mediaItems]`, which give you the address of a returned temporary object.

It should be `&_mediaItems` i.e. the address of the underlying ivar.

Comment: In general this will work but it is worth noting that this code is likely to cause crashes. The problem with a derived data source property like this is that it can change while the collection view is reloading in between data source calls, which can cause a number of exceptions, most commonly an out of range exception trying to access a nonexistent array index. Ideally, there would be an actual backing ivar that is modified at the same time a view reload is triggered.

Comment: @Dima Yes. The better solution is to separate them out. One view/view controller should only responsible for one page.

Comment: Dima is correct in saying the data source could change without you knowing. If you want them in the same view controller, I'd make a new NSArray property which is used as the datasource for the collection view, then when you set activePage (custom setter or kvo), set the NSArray property with either mediaItems or likesItems